# Cannot call value of non-function type 'Object'

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have an error while trying to parse json, I don't know what went wrong actually. since I want to save the iteration of an object and an error appear

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'Movie'

can you tell me why is error? this is my code

```
static func movies(fromJSON data: Data) -> Result<[Movie], MovieError> {

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

        do {
            let jsonData = try decoder.decode(MovieItem.self, from: data)
            var items = [Movie]()

            for movie in jsonData.results {
                // this is the line an error appear in movie(fromJSON: movie)
                if let movie = movie(fromJSON: movie) {
                    items.append(movie)
                }
            }

            return .success(items)
        } catch {
            return .failure(.failedToParseJSON)
        }
    }

    private static func movie(fromJSON movie: Movie) -> Movie? {
        let id = movie.id
        let title = movie.title
        let releaseDate = movie.releaseDate
        let overview = movie.overview
        let posterPath = movie.posterPath

        return Movie(id: id, title: title, releaseDate: releaseDate, overview: overview, posterPath: posterPath)
    }
```

Comment: Unrelated but why do you create a `Movie` from a `Movie`? And why is the return value optional? Both makes no sense at all. Why not just `return .success(jsonData.results)`

Comment: I try to recreate from book I read iOS Big Nerd Ranch, the book save the iteration like I show you. but the difference is it used JSONSerialization instead I use JSONDecoder. in private static function movie() the book use example movie(fromJSON: [String: Any]) -> Movie?. I try to recreate that but the error appear like I show you @vadian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression

```
 for movie in jsonData.results {
      // this is the line an error appear in movie(fromJSON: movie)
      if let movie = movie(fromJSON: movie) {
          items.append(movie)
      }
 }
```

uses three(!) different `movie` variables. This confuses the compiler. Rename the method for example

```
private static func createMovie(fromJSON movie: Movie) -> Movie? { ...
```

and

```
if let movie = createMovie(fromJSON: movie) {
   items.append(movie)
}
```

---

By the way most of your code is redundant. And never return a meaningless custom error in a `Decoding` context, return the real `DecodingError`.

Actually you can replace your entire code with this

```
static func movies(fromJSON data: Data) -> Result<[Movie], Error> {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    return Result{ try decoder.decode(MovieItem.self, from: data).results }
}
```

Comment: so it's because there is more name of movie, I didn't know that. it's a new learning from me. thank you again @vadian